# Is there a way to change the color of keyframes?

Tags: animation, interface, keyframes, customization, timeline

Is there a way to change the color of keyframes on the timeline? For example, I would like all the keyframes associated with the Left Leg to be Blue and the Right Leg to be Green.

Comment: I don't think so... different keyframe colors represent different things in the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

As of v3.5, Blender does not allow to fully customize individual keyframes look, let alone depending on rules such as their bones or channels.

However, there is some customization possible.

Keyframes have four [types](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/introduction.html#keyframe-types)  (menu `Key` > `Keyframe Type`). These are purely visual and don't affect the behavior of keyframes.

Combine this with some [theme customization](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/182165/53447)  and you can do some things you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change the colors of *all* keyframes. If you go into the user preferences and go to `Themes > Dope Sheet` then you can change the colors of selected and unselected keyframes.

I could be wrong, but after using Blender for two or three years I have not seen a way to change keyframe colors for individual bones. Would be a nice feature have for sure.

Comment: I like the idea too, but in thinking about this more, I wonder if the issue with this suggestion is that, unlike so many other elements in the scene, such as items in the Outliner, which have an independent location in the list, or objects in the 3D view, which have a discrete position in space, different keyframes often find themselves directly on top of each other on a given time position in the timeline, meaning you'd have no way to see them independently. So, depending on the situation, the color differences between various keyframes would often be undetectable.